# How to debug mavenized C++ project on Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, maven

I have debugged C++ projects on Eclipse but when I try to debug a mavenized C++ project adding breakpoints and start debug mode on Eclipse, flow isn't stopping on the breakpoints and exiting immediately. Also I made sure my debug configurations of my project are fine on Eclipse. Is there a way or option to specify on maven while building, such that my executable is debug enabled?

I looked at the similar questions, didn't find a proper solution.

Comment: What platform are you compiling on? (This will determine how you inspect executable for "does it have debug symbols"). However, it sounds more like your "run" is aborting due to for example "no command line arguments" or similar. If there are no debug symbols, the debugger would give you errors for that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm compiling it on CentOS 64bit. No my program doesn't expect any command line arguments.